# XML parsing, illegal xml character

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have created a fairly large procedure importing thousands of xml files.
The procedure runs smoothly until I hit a file that contains an illegal xml character. This character appears to resemble the female symbol.I was unable to paste it to the body of this question.

Below is my basic code to read an xml file. When the specific file is run, I get:

> Msg 9420, lvl 16, state 1, line 5. XML parsing: line 1800, character 150, illegal xml character. Encoding is in ANSI

---

```
Declare @xml xml
select @xml = T
from OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Path', SINGLE_BLOB as Transactions (T)
```

Again the code wont read the file. Has anyone ever experienced this symbol and how can it be systematically erased/replaced?

Comment: Is the troublesome character anywhere on this [list](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)?

Comment: try to switch to a UTF encoding, rather than ANSI

Comment: @Parfait it maybe be the female symbol. (&female)

Comment: If I were to try and replace the female symbol out of my xml file as I am import it with the openrowset, what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: See how to replace text in blob: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337814/replacing-text-in-an-blob-column