# Msg 9420 illegal xml character, How to replace?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a stored proc that reads thousands of xml files using openrowset dynamically.

However within my xml files there are a few instances where the female symbol(♀) shows up in a specific  <>. This results in a XML parsing error 9420. I was wondering how I could remove/replace/ignore the symbol when trying to read the xml file. Saving the file to UTF-8 does not work and would be inconvenient since I have thousands of files.

Below is the code I use to read an xml file...

```
Declare @xml xml
Select @xml = t
from OPENROWSET (Bulk 'C:\path', SINGLE_BLOB) as Transactions(T)
select @xml
```

Comment: can this help you http://joaodepaula.com/articles/invalidxmlcharacter.html

Comment: You can't do it in the XML toolchain since the document is not well-formed XML. You'll need to preprocess the document using regexp or some such thing to correct the bad data. Better yet, fix whatever process is sending you malformed XML.

Comment: This is something best handled in the CLR.

Comment: Why did you ask a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35855664/xml-parsing-illegal-xml-character) a day part?

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to have the system that is writing these files either not include the symbol, or insure they are setting the correct encoding at the top: example: 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` or `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>` (i'm not sure which encoding is needed for that character).

You can also use an SSIS package to pull in the data and cleanse it.  Either throw out the entire record into a trash table, or filter off the character and insure it's encoding to UTF-8 standards.  I prefer using SSIS to pull in flat file data, as it has a lot better handling of trash/bad data.

A 3rd option would be to pull in the record as a string, strip the character with a REPLACE and then convert it into XML.