# Replacing text inside blob

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I got quite large xml saved in BLOB and I need to edit value its value. 
I'm trying following

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE 
SET MY_BLOB=REPLACE(CONVERT(MY_BLOB USING UTF8), 'oldValue', 'newValue') 
WHERE MY_ID = 'someID'
```

Still, I keep getting SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

but srsly, where do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

CONVERT needs a least two input parameters and is not for BLOB

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337814/replacing-text-in-an-blob-column) is useful information about update a text in BLOB column.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider converting blob to clob and then calling replace function on it. Some useful info: http://fazlansabar.blogspot.com/2012/03/replace-function-for-blob-fields-in.html